# Count an external signal in VHDL FSM

Tags: vhdl, fsm

I need your help to count and external signal. Basically i need to count an external signal (in my vhdl i call it sync100k) and count it in order to generate a signal active high (pulse_v) for programable number of counts. sync100k will be high for 50 ns and 0 for 450 ns, for a period of 500ns, so if i set the count to 1, i expected that pulse_v is high for 500ns, so if i set the count to 3 i exprected that pulse_v is high for 1500ns. I wrote a simple vhdl code but it doesn't work properly. If i set the registry index to count 1, the signal generated doesn't stay high for 500ns as expected but only fo 50 ns. If set the index to count 2, it generate a signal of 500ns, if set an index of 3, he generate a signal fo 550ns, and so on. Maybe i miss something in my fsm, but i still not figure out where is the bug.

Here my code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

entity millipulse is
generic(N : integer := 8);
Port (
        start : in STD_LOGIC := '0'; --start
        pps : in STD_LOGIC :='0'; --pps 
        clk : in  STD_LOGIC; --clock 
        reset  : in  STD_LOGIC; -- reset
        sync100k : in STD_LOGIC; --100kHz sync signal 
        pulse: out STD_LOGIC; --pulse out
        t_on: in std_logic_vector (N-1 downto 0) --count vector

    );
end millipulse;

architecture behavioral of millipulse is
    --type state_type is (idle, gate_up, final);
    type state_type is (idle, wakeup, lighton);
    signal state : state_type;


begin


    process (reset, clk, start, pps, sync100k, t_on)
    variable index : integer :=0;
    variable pulse_v: std_logic;
    variable t_onlen : integer;

    begin
    t_onlen := to_integer(unsigned(t_on));

    if reset = '1' then 
      index := 0;
      pulse_v := '0';  
    else
        if rising_edge(clk) then
        case state is
          when idle =>
            index := 0;
            pulse_v :='0';
            if(start = '1') then
              state <= wakeup;
              index := 0;
              pulse_v :='0';
            else
              state <= idle;
            end if;

            when wakeup =>
            if (pps='1') then
            state <= lighton;
            else
            state <= wakeup;
            end if;

            when lighton =>
            if (sync100k = '1') then
              if index = t_onlen then
               pulse_v := '0';
               state <=wakeup;
               else
               pulse_v := '1';
               index := index + 1;
               state <= lighton;
               end if;
            end if;


          when others => null;
        end case;

   end if;
    end if;     
    pulse <= pulse_v;
  end process; 


end Behavioral;
```

here my test bench

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY millipulse_tb IS
END millipulse_tb;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF millipulse_tb IS 

        signal clk : std_logic := '0';
        signal reset : std_logic := '0'; 
        signal start : std_logic := '0';
        signal pps : std_logic := '0';
        signal sync100k : std_logic := '0';
        signal pulse : std_logic := '0'; --this is the light pulse 
        signal t_on : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);   --time light on
        constant clk_period : time := 25 ns;


        component millipulse is 
        port( 
            clk : in std_logic;  
            reset : in std_logic;
            start : in std_logic;           
            pps: in std_logic;
            sync100k : in std_logic;
            pulse: out std_logic;
            t_on: in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)
            ---start : in STD_LOGIC := '0'
        );
    end component millipulse;





BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: millipulse PORT MAP (
          clk => clk,
          reset => reset,
          start => start,
          pps=> pps,
          sync100k=> sync100k,
          pulse => pulse,
          t_on => t_on

        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   millipulse_process :process
   begin
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
   end process;

stim : process 
    begin
    t_on <= "00000011";
    wait for 100 ns;
    reset <='1';
    wait for 100 ns;
    reset <='0';
    wait for 100 ns;
    start <= '1';
    wait for 100 ns;
    start <='0';
    wait for 1 ns;
    wait for 100 ns;
    pps <='1';
    wait for 100 ns;
    pps <='0';
    wait for 200 ns;
    sync100k <= '1';
    wait for 50 ns;
    sync100k <= '0';
    wait for 450 ns;
    sync100k <= '1';
    wait for 50 ns;
    sync100k <= '0';
    wait for 450 ns;
    sync100k <= '1';
    wait for 50 ns;
    sync100k <= '0';
    wait for 450 ns;
    sync100k <= '1';
    wait for 50 ns;
    sync100k <= '0';
    wait for 450 ns;
    sync100k <= '1';
    wait for 50 ns;
    sync100k <= '0';
    wait for 450 ns;
    sync100k <= '1';
    wait for 50 ns;
    sync100k <= '0';
    wait for 450 ns;
    sync100k <= '1';
    wait for 50 ns;
    sync100k <= '0';
    wait for 450 ns;


    wait for 1000 ns;



    end process;


END behavior;
```

I see the code but i did't see where is the wrong step on this FSM. Any help will be greatly appreciate!

Comment: I can't follow your description. This: *"This signal will be high for 50 ns .."* contradicts *" the signal generated doesn't stay high for 500ns as expected"*.  Also I do not see how your description matches *"i need to count an external signal"*

Comment: [Your testbench has been modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1F8t.jpg) to illustrate your textual description. What do the differences of t_on values tell you about what your state machine isn't doing right?

Comment: Dear Oldfart, i try to explain better, the extarnal signal that i need to count is high for 50ns and low for 450. I need to count it and generate a "gate" signal active high for all the signal period (500ns total) for a fixed number of cicle. IE. if i set the count to 3, i to generate a "gate" active on for 500ns x 3...and so on. But my code, in simulation doesn't do this.

Comment: But my code, in simulation doesn't do this. Btw i edit the description in order to explain better what i need to do and what the code does

Comment: Dear user1155120, my code work ask you simulete, but i don't need that it work on it. I need that pulse will be "on" for a total period of 500 for each count value set. So for t_on = 1 i expected to have pulse active high for 500ns, for t_on = 2 for 1000 and so on. As your simulation show, for a value of 4, i obtain a pulse of (roughly) 1000ns and not 2000 as expected.

Comment: [You can use sync100k to generate an enable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZOtL.jpg).  It has the side effect of being able to use just the index counter (and a counter is a state machine). If this isn't suitable it's because you haven't described the purpose of all you inputs (note start isn't used, sync100k needs to have as many pulses as 500 ns intervals pulse can be high plus 1).

Comment: Dear user1155120, unfortunatly i need to keep the start (is a signal coming from the fsm that store the number of sync100k count that i need in its register, so it useful for me to "arm" the millisecond pulse only when i'm sure that its register is set, so when the register is set i reiceve this start signal. Of course i need to generate this pulse active high after a signal that was send every second (pps).

Comment: Of curse i can use the first sync100k signal as an enable for another fsm state and generate the lenght of the pulse using the counter and counting my clock, but basically i prefere to count the period of the sync100k and not just use this signal for start the clock counter.